# Replace All method in Strings

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

I want to replace a character in string with the replace all method, but this method gives me still the same string.

```
String example = "5x";
example.replaceAll(Character.toString('x') , Integer.toString(1));
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You should always read the documentation first.

Comment: You are right, I was just in a hurry. I will keep in mind for next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String` is immutable. You should do something like

```
example = example.replaceAll(Character.toString('x') , Integer.toString(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, meaning they can not be changed.

This can be done simply like this:

```
String example = "5x";
example = example.replaceAll("x", Integer.toString(1));
```

You are missing assigning the new string to example.